# Do I have to file for tax if I don't work at all but just received 1098-T form from my college?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tuition

I don't work at all right now. So I thought I wouldn't have to pay for taxes. But then I got this 1098-T form from my college a month ago. So now I'm confused. Can I/Do I still have to file for tax without any W2 form from jobs? The only document I have is that 1098-T.

Comment: Can your parents or anybody else claim you as a dependent?

Comment: Related: [Do I need to file a tax return as a student?](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/58563/10997)

Answer (score 4):

The [1098-T](https://www.irs.gov/uac/Form-1098-T,-Tuition-Statement) is not an income statement.  It is a statement of the tuition that was paid on your behalf.  Normally, this form is used by the taxpayer to claim [educational tax benefits](https://www.irs.gov/uac/Tax-Benefits-for-Education:-Information-Center).

If you have no income, and if you did not receive any *taxable* scholarships or tuition reduction, you are not *required* to file a tax return.

If your parents or someone else claims you as a dependent on their taxes, you should give this form to them.  They may be able to use it to get a reduction on their taxes.

If there is no one that will claim you as a dependent, it is sometimes possible to claim the American Opportunity Tax Credit (AOTC) and get a refund even if you don't pay any tax.  See the [IRS page on the AOTC](https://www.irs.gov/Individuals/AOTC) for details.